# How to execute more than one commands by Process in Swift MacOS

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I want to do the following actions:
1.change directory in to /Applications
2.open any app for example: open QQ.app

I successfully execute the following commands in CML:
1.cd /Applications
2.open QQ.app

I tried the following code but it doesn’t work:

```
let process = Process()
process.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
process.arguments = ["cd /Applications"]
process.launch()

let process2 = Process()
process2.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
process2.arguments = ["open QQ.app"]
process2.launch()
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding;

```
 process.waitUntilExit()
```

before

```
 process2.launch()
```

Alternately you can add a termination handler on process and call process2 when the first handler runs.